# Sitecore and Swashbuckle

Tags: sitecore, swagger, sitecore-mvc, swashbuckle, asp.net-mvc-apiexplorer

I've been trying to document my Sitecore WebApi using Swashbuckle, but no luck. I've installed the `Swashbuckle.Core` Nuget package, and added this logic to an `Initialize` pipeline processor:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger();
```

I run this processor after adding my custom route to the Routes, using `MapRoute`. I've found out Swashbuckle uses `System.Web.Http.Description.ApiExplorer` to get a list of all controllers and actions. And indeed, every standard Sitecore API is listed, but not my custom controller and action, added in my custom route! Can anyone with experience in the `ApiExplorer` tell me how to debug this? Could [this mentioned bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14514090/1921754) still be an issue? Can I configure the `ApiExplorer` to just print my custom controller and action, and not every default Sitecore API?

Thanks in advance!